# Implementar AJAX en una web dinamica basada en PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, programación-funcional, ecmascript-2015

Estoy implementando un blog desde cero con **PHP** y **MySQL** y pues, lo estoy terminando pero solo con estos lenguajes. No he usado **Javascript** y mucho menos **Ajax** para pasar `clave:valor`, por lo que ni bien termine el sistema, estoy pensando en añadirle funciones con **AJAX** para hacerla lo más asíncronamente dinámica posible.

Mi pregunta es:

¿**Es o no** posible, implementar AJAX después de terminar todo el sistema del blog con PHP? De no ser posible, ¿Por qué?

> Esta pregunta se responde con sí o no, o simplemente con alguna sugerencia.

En otras palabras, y para hacer más comprensible la pregunta.

Luego de terminar el blog, ¿Puedo añadir funciones **AJAX** sin tener ningún conflicto con el sistema ya terminado? o ¿Es necesario plantearse "ANTES" de crear el sistema, el uso de **AJAX** para incorporarlo durante el desarrollo del sistema?

Comment: Compañeros, no se si entiende bien pero simplemente estoy pidiendo un SI o un NO de algun experto. Y no esta demas alguna recomendación, es todo lo que les pido. Acabo de hacerlo en la version en ingles de stackoverflow y ya me respondieron sin decir que esta duplicada a pesar de que la version en ingles tiene mas tiempo que la version en español. No se dejen llevar por el facilismo de decir que esta duplicada simplemente y demonos la molestia de leer el contenido en detalle y asi crecer juntos. Saludos y gracias de todas maneras.

Comment: OP tiene razon... y me gustaria un link a la pregunta en ingles, si quieres traducir la respuesta seria bueno tambien

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384524/implementing-ajax-on-a-php-dynamic-web-based-after-it-is-completed-is-it-an-eff

Comment: Claro que puedes. Solo necesitas modificar algunas de tus funciones en php para que devuelva datos en JSON en lugar de una vista. Y en el lado del cliente usar Javascript para acceder a esos datos usando AJAX y renderizar el html deseado. Asi que en resumen si, puedes hacerlo asi, es bastante comun.

Comment: Amigo puedes implementar AJAX en un proyecto ya terminado, sin embargo es dificil asegurarte que no tendras que cambiar tu codigo. Me imagino que tienes funciones en PHP que reciben parametros y retornan valores. Tendras que modificar ciertos puntos especificos de tu proyecto sobre todo donde muestras valores o eliminas o editas otros.

Comment: @gbianchi Aqui te paso el link a la pregunta en ingles que realice amigo pero yo me defiendo muy bien en el idioma yankee asi que no sera necesario jeje. Y sioesi es verdad ahora estoy teniendo problemas para pasar de PHP a AJAX y al parecer voy a tener que sumar mas codigo aparte que recupere las llamadas de AJAX. Saludos a uds y les agfradesco mucho el interes.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384524/how-to-efficiently-implement-ajax-on-a-dynamic-php-website-after-it-is-completed